# How to use append and remove for changing html forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I am working on this project on Wordpress and I need to use append and remove for dynamically changing forms in html. I tried using that, but there is some errors. It's not working the way it's supposed to be. This is brief description of the code:

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: FirstStarRatingSystem */      
?>

<div class="t1">
<button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-
size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button><br>    
<input type="text" class="t1" name="fname1" id="text1" placeholder="First 
Rating"></div>
<div class="rating1"> 
<legend>Please rate:</legend>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="star5" name="rating1" value="5" />
<label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="star4" name="rating1" value="4" />
<label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="star3" name="rating1" value="3" />
<label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="star2" name="rating1" value="2" />
<label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="star1" name="rating1" value="1" />
<label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="t2"></div>
<div class="rating2"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields=2;
var t2=$(".t2");
var rating2=$(".rating2");
var add_button=$(".add_form_field");

var x=1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){
x++;
if(x==2)

$(t2).append('<div class="t2"><input type="text" class="t2" name="fname2" 
id="text2" placeholder="Second Rating"></div>'); //add input box 

$(rating2).append('<div class="rating2"><legend>Please rate1:</legend> 
<input type="radio" class="rating2" id="1star5" name="rating2" value="5" /> 
<label for="1star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label> <input type="radio" 
class="rating2" id="1star4" name="rating2" value="4" /> <label for="1star4" 
title="Pretty good">4 stars</label> <input type="radio" class="rating2" 
id="1star3" name="rating2" value="3" /> <label for="1star3" title="Meh">3 
stars</label> <input type="radio" class="rating2" id="1star2" name="rating2" 
value="2" /> <label for="1star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label> <input 
type="radio" class="rating2" id="1star1" name="rating2" value="1" /> <label 
for="1star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label><a href="#" 
class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add 5 star rating.
}
 else
 {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
 }
 });

  $(rating2).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(t2).remove();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();

     x--;
   })
  });

  </script>

  <style>NECESSARY CSS</style>
```

As you would have figured out, that this code is for displaying a dynamic input form along with a 5 star rating system. The user can select number of input form and 5 star rating required. Currently, for testing purposes this number is limited to 2 number of times only(var max_fields = 2;). I need to add both input form and 5 star rating at the same time user presses add button and also remove a input form and 5 star rating at the same time when user presses delete button, but currently this is not working properly and causes second added input form to be deleted permanently and only 5 star rating is working properly ie. getting added and deleted properly.

Thanking in advance.

First image shows first output before adding second input form and 5 star rating:

[image]

Second image shows after pressing "Add New Field +" Button after deletion of second input form and 5 star rating:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually because your container for your input field having the same class name which is `t2`, so by the below, you're removing both (container and the input field and the defined t2 element from your HTML).

```
$(rating2).on("click",".delete", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $(t2).remove();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();

  x--;
})
```

So by the time you're appending, `t2`container is no longer available from the DOM.
So var `t2` refer to null value so `append` will not work.

You should do something like this.

```
$(rating2).on("click",".delete", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $(t2).find('input').remove(); // find the input element and remove
  $(this).parent('div').remove();

  x--;
})
```

**OR** change your input field class to something not similar to your container

**your declaration**

```
var t2=$(".t2");
```

**how you append**

```
$(t2).append('<div class="t2"><input type="text" class="t2" name="fname2" id="text2" placeholder="Second Rating"></div>');
```

**how you remove**

```
$(t2).remove();
```

Comment: If possible can you give any resources for knowing more about this topic?Thanks.

Comment: hmmm I don't have any exact articles or references from that topic, it's actually based totally on experience. :) You will learn more based on experience, so keep on doing what you're doing and don't be afraid to commit mistakes, that's how you will learn effectively.